# Hi.. I used a landscape table in my thesis and need some help

Tags: landscape

As my landscape give the page numbering in left side but i need to show in buttom of the page as to show the continuous numbers. I past here the pic

[image]

```
 %% pjhus extracted contours and volume 
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[tbp]\centering
    \caption{Expert evaluation of cardiac function and oedema volume}
    \label{Tab:pj1}



    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}\hline

        \textbf{Patient ID} & \textbf{Pathology} & \textbf{Gander} & \textbf{Age} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf {Generated-Contours }} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Ground-Truth Volume}}\\\cline{5-10}
        & & & &\textbf{Outer (\%)}&\textbf{Inner (\%)}&\textbf{EDV (ml)}&\textbf{ESV (ml)}&\textbf{EF (\%)}&\textbf{oedema (\%)}\\\hline
        Patient-A001&   A001&   Male &  57& 83.23&  96.30&  106&    72& 32& 43\\
        Patient-A002&   A002    &Male&  46& 87.68&  97.00&  111&    51& 54& 17\\
        Patient-A003&   A003&   Male&   58& 82.00&  96.87&  177&97& 45& 30\\
        Patient-A004&   A004    &Male&  48& 82.56&  98.00&  173&    98& 43&     29\\\hline
        \textbf{Mean Average}   &-&-&-&         84.6&96.4&144.8&80.3&45.3&36.7\\    
        \textbf{SD}&-&-&-&    2.63&1.42&34.28&27.63&8.38&10.79\\

        \hline  
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: I need a help to show the page numbers in bottom not in side

Comment: Hello. I think it would be interesting to know what your current code is and what you already tried and found not to work. See [these guidelines](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/proposal-can-we-add-a-tutorialadmission-test-for-new-users/7399#7399).

Comment: @ysalmon please see my table code i edited

Comment: Did you try solutions that come up when searching for ```landscape page number position``` (search field at top right corner of the page) ?

Comment: @ysalmon actually i am new in latex ok i search hope i find

Comment: @ysalmon actually i need in table format becouse i only used landscap for table and figures and not for text

Comment: There is no need to put *Hi* in the question title. Same is true for asking for help. Everbody asking a question here needs help, that is the whole point of this website.

Comment: @amjad Can you give your question a more meaningful title that will also help future users with the same problem to find it?

Comment: @amjad While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: @samcarter sorry for late reply i was searching the problem ... Ok I EDIT THE QUESTION Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "`\begin{landscape}`" use "`\begin{sidewaystable}`", codes are mentioned below:

```
\usepackage{rotating,floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{...}
\begin{tabular}
....
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Hope this help you to meet your expectations..

Please find the updated tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
    \caption{Expert evaluation of cardiac function and oedema volume}
    \label{Tab:pj1}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}\hline

        \textbf{Patient ID} & \textbf{Pathology} & \textbf{Gander} & \textbf{Age} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf {Generated-Contours }} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Ground-Truth Volume}}\\\cline{5-10}
        & & & &\textbf{Outer (\%)}&\textbf{Inner (\%)}&\textbf{EDV (ml)}&\textbf{ESV (ml)}&\textbf{EF (\%)}&\textbf{oedema (\%)}\\\hline
        Patient-A001&   A001&   Male &  57& 83.23&  96.30&  106&    72& 32& 43\\
        Patient-A002&   A002    &Male&  46& 87.68&  97.00&  111&    51& 54& 17\\
        Patient-A003&   A003&   Male&   58& 82.00&  96.87&  177&97& 45& 30\\
        Patient-A004&   A004    &Male&  48& 82.56&  98.00&  173&    98& 43&     29\\\hline
        \textbf{Mean Average}   &-&-&-&         84.6&96.4&144.8&80.3&45.3&36.7\\    
        \textbf{SD}&-&-&-&    2.63&1.42&34.28&27.63&8.38&10.79\\

        \hline  
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I check this one first

Comment: can you plz test this on my table becouse i got error

Comment: please check the updated answer...